# Get the rules fired in redhat BRMS back in Java

Tags: java, rule-engine, redhat-brms

We are using Redhat BRMS 6.4 for our application which is developed using Java. For better logging capabilities, I was thinking of logging the rules fired in Redhat BRMS. Is there a way we can get back the rules fired in BRMS back as response.

```
KieCommands commandsFactory = KieServices.Factory.get().getCommands();
    String className = getClassNameForRuleEngine(t);
    commands.add(commandsFactory.newInsert(t, className));
    commands.add(commandsFactory.newFireAllRules());
    commands.add(commandsFactory.newGetObjects(GET_DEFAULT_OBJECT_NAME));
    BatchExecutionCommand batchExecution = commandsFactory.newBatchExecution(commands, "ksession");
    RuleServicesClient ruleServicesClient = kieServicesClient.getServicesClient(RuleServicesClient.class);
    ServiceResponse<ExecutionResults> response = ruleServicesClient.executeCommandsWithResults(containerId,
            batchExecution);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using agendaeventlistner you can log the rules fired in Redhat BRMS

For more info,pleasego through the [link](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/jboss-drools/jboss-drools-agendaeventlistener-example/) which explain that how to use agendaeventlistner.